# Como validar el input con Css para darle un estilo a su label?

Tags: css, css-transform

Tengo el siguiente codigo.

```css
.form-group{
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 2.5rem;
    padding-top:1rem;
}

.form-group label{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    transform: translate(16px, 16px);
    transform-origin: left;
    transition: transform .25s;
    color: #bfbfbf;
    width: 90%;
}
.form-group:focus-within label{
    transform: translate(0, -6px) scale(.8);
    color: #707070;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
    <input class="form-control" type="text" id="url" aria-describedby="namelHelp" required>
    <label for="url">Full Name</label>
    <small id="namelHelp" class="form-text text-muted"></small>
</div>
```

El efecto esta super genial pero necesito validar con css el hecho de que el input ya no esté vacío para poder establecer unos estilos finales de dicho label cuando el usuario ya haya introducido los datos en el input.

Comment: No puedes hacerlo con css, tienes que validar con javascript y de nuevo con javascript aplicas un nuevo estilo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quizás esto te sirva, usando la pseudoclase [:valid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:valid) e invocando a su elemento hermano *label* mediante el [selector CSS](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_combinators.asp) `+`. Agrégalo a tu css y pruébalo (no estoy seguro que sea compatible en todos los navegadores):

```
.form-group > input:valid + label{
    transform: translate(0, -6px) scale(.8);
    color: #707070;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Ejemplo:

```css
.form-group {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 2.5rem;
  padding-top: 1rem;
}

.form-group label {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transform: translate(16px, 16px);
  transform-origin: left;
  transition: transform .25s;
  color: #bfbfbf;
  width: 90%;
}

.form-group:focus-within label {
  transform: translate(0, -6px) scale(.8);
  color: #707070;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.form-group>input:valid+label {
  transform: translate(0, -6px) scale(.8);
  color: #707070;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <input class="form-control" type="text" id="url" aria-describedby="namelHelp" required>
  <label for="url">Full Name</label>
  <small id="namelHelp" class="form-text text-muted"></small>
</div>
```

Comment: Excelente hermano, funciono perfecto.
Añado otra alternativa que pude encontrar pero no sirve para el caso de un text area. Seria con javascript
<input type="email" value="" placeholder="valid mail" onchange="this.setAttribute('value', this.value);" />